# How to store a broken-Scheme-string in an array or a vector?

Tags: arrays, string, vector, char, scheme

I get as an input a string , and I want to store it in an array or 
a vector , so I would be able to check the values of the broken string .

Here I break the string into chars :

```
(define (dealBreaker str) (string->list str))  ; break the string into chars
```

But when I try to declare a simple vector :

```
(define (myVector (make-vector 4 (/ 1 2))))
```

I get this : `#%plain-lambda: not an identifier in: (make-vector 4 (/ 1 2))`

How can I declare a vector called `someVector` for the broken characters from `dealBreaker` method above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, for some `str` string:

```
(define (dealBreaker str)
  (list->vector (string->list str)))

(define myVector (dealBreaker "some string"))

myVector
=> '#(#\s #\o #\m #\e #\space #\s #\t #\r #\i #\n #\g)
```

The above will create a new vector from the characters in the string, is that what you need?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `define` should be

```
(define identifier value)
```

but right now you have

```
(define (identifier value))
```

So try

```
(define myVector (make-vector 4 (/ 1 2)))
```

It's a little confusing, because in Scheme, define is overloaded, there's also

```
(define (functionName formals) body)
```

but that's purely syntactical sugar for

```
(define functionName
    (lambda formals body))
```

Side note: Several beginner scheme textbooks recommend using the lambda version since it's more explicit.

In this case though, just do:

```
 (define myVec (list->vector (dealBreaker str)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem you're having with `myVector` appears to be due to a misplaced paren - try this instead and see if it resolves the 'plain-lambda' error:

```
(define myVector (make-vector 4 (/ 1 2)))
```

On the question of converting the 'dealBreaker' string to a vector, you should be able to do this:

```
(define (someVector dealBreakerList) (list->vector dealBreakerList))

(someVector (dealBreaker "someString"))
```

Or if you want 'someVector' as the complete function:

```
(define (someVector str) (list->vector (string->list str)))

(someVector "someString")
```

Comment: (define myVector2 (make-vector 4 (/ 1 2)))